# Function not recognized from jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a .js file that has this function in it:

```
function showDialog(divID) 
{
    alert("got here");

    var dialogDiv = $(divID);

    dialogDiv.dialog
    (
        {
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'blind'
        }
    )

    dialogDiv.dialog("open");
}
```

And in my page this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $("input.invokeDialog").click.showDialog("#testDialog");
    });

</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't recognize my showDialog function.  Is it not possible to reference it with the dot as I am doing?  Do I need a jQuery specific function or syntax for it to know that it's a jQuery function or is there no such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(function()
    {
        $("input.invokeDialog").click(function(){
           showDialog("#testDialog");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I get the error ": expected" for showDialog in Visual Studio in ASP.NET when working in the mark-up.

Comment: That should work perfectly. Could you please tell us what did not work? Is it not showing the dialog? And could you post the whole showDialog function. It got cut off.

Comment: When I click the button, nothing is happening even if I put an alert in the showDialog function.

Comment: If you put an alert right above the showDialog call in the code above, does that show up?

Comment: Does your input element have class="invokeDialog" in it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `click.showDialog("#testDialog")` is that it means you are trying to call a function called `showDialog` which is part of the `click` object.  You have defined the `showDialog` function as a free-floating function, so you don't need anything in front of it to call it.

The code in Sarfraz's answer should work well for what you're trying to do.

Comment: so how would you recommend calling free-floating functions outside of Sarfaz's suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        showDialog("#testDialog");
    });

</script>
```

What about this?

Comment: that's not tied to any DOM element..it will never be called.

Comment: Yeah I meant to hook it to document onload... after reading a few other comments I decided that you're probably not gonna even try that one. So just left it to see what commentary you did add.

Comment: I think drachenstern is trying to narrow down whether the problem is occurring in the binding of the click event, or in the calling of the showDialog function itself.

The $ in this case is a synonym for $(document).ready().  It will be called as soon as the document is finished loading.  The code in your question uses the same syntax. :)